# PyQt GUI freezes until threads are finished while multithreading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt4, freeze

The code is pretty heavy so I will just post some snippets.

```
class Program(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
```

...

```
def main():   
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    global ex
    ex = Program()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And in between I have a bunch of labels, text fields, buttons and 4 QListWidgets inside sublayouts, these sublayouts are added to the grid.

I'm launching variable number of threads depending on input. Normally 4 threads. They are launched in own class:

```
class myThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, arguments, more_arguments):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def work_it(self, argument, more_arguments):
        Program.some_function_in_Program_class(ex, arguments)
```

And from there I call functions inside the Program() class to do the actual changes to the GUI.

```
Program.generate_results(ex, arguments, arguments2, more_arguments)
```

In the end it comes down to a list I iterate over and whether I print each element or I use:

```
my_listbox.addItem(item)
```

It freezes the GUI until all 4 threads are finished going through the list. Then all the results appear together instead of appearing one by one.

I have done this in Tkinter and I could see one by one list item appear in the ListBox widgets dynamically, without freezing the GUI.

As for managing threads what I'm doing is I'm iterating over a list and according to its length I make a number of threads:

```
threadlist = []
for i in self.results:
    sub_thread = myThread(i, self.results[i])
    self.threadlist.append(sub_thread)
swapAndWaitThread = spawnAndWaitThreadsThread(self.threadlist)
swapAndWaitThread.start()
```

I do this to be able to manage these 4 threads and be able to tell when they are finished.

```
class spawnAndWaitThreadsThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadlist):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadlist = threadlist

    def run(self):
        for thread in self.threadlist:
            thread.start()

        for thread in self.threadlist:
            thread.join()

    print "threads finished.. do something"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if you know this or not, but just inheriting from `Thread` isn't enough to make a piece of code multithreaded. For example, for threads inheriting from [`threading.thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects), you need to put the desired code in its `run` method, and then call `start` at some point. Code that appears inside, say, the `__init__` method, will still run in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It's a bit more complicated. I have updated my question to answer your comment. First I make a list of threads in my Program class function. I then send this list to a thread class which starts and joins threads so I can find out when all of them are finished. And when these threads are started (myThread class) they call some function again in the Program class where I want to update my GUI from.

Comment: Perhaps I'm incorrectly calling Program() functions from Thread() functions? I struggled because at first I tried to call them by simply Program.some_function(arguments).. but kept getting an error about program instance not being passed. So I had to come up with a dirty (?) fix by declaring "ex" as a global variable and passing it as a Program() instance argument. Is that correct way to do it?

Comment: The "official" way to get the program instance to your threads is to add a parameter to the threads' `run` definition and start the threads like `thread.start(args = (my_program_instance,))`, but a global variable ought to work too. In general, your `spawnAndWaitThreadsThread` looks OK to me. I think the next place I'd look for problems is inside `myThread`

Comment: So if one goes through hundreds and hundreds of files (os.path.listdir), filters them by some extensions, pulls out their timestamps, concatenates the results to a string and then tries to write one by one these hundreds of strings on the fly to multiple QListWidgets it shouldn't freeze the program, right?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding a very simple function in the main Program() class which has only one job - to start a very simple thread which in turn goes back to Program() class and calls a function there which then starts constructing my threads list, sending them to another thread class, etc.

As a result GUI is not freezing anymore.

Comment: did not get. please elaborate with an example if you cannot put your actual code